# I just cannot get an object to bend along a curve properly

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

Using Blender 2.93.5 on MacOS 12.0.1

This is embarrassing.  I just cannot seem to get an object to bend properly along a curve, with no deformations.  I have followed various tutorials to no avail.  I am trying to bend the curve (seat) along the path Seat Curve.  Goal is to make a U-Shape, sort of like a swing (but this will be a chair seat made from wood).  I have attached some of the comical twisted results, but the blender file will be useful, I am sure.

[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhpOt.png)
[image]
[image]

I am attaching the blender file.  I have added enough cuts to the seat object, set the origins close to the "starting points" and even moved them both the the "center."  The results are comically frustrating.  I have watched 3 tutorials, and still cannot get it.

[image]

--Update--

Okay, with playing with the scaling I was able to do it, but it just seems odd that the tutorials don't seem to mention this.  IT WORKS, but sometimes you get unexpected results.  Good to know.  Thank you for feedback.

Here is updated file:
[enter link description here](http://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SbYzkNRg%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.com/b/SbYzkNRg/))

just an odd point, I notice that the final result is very faceted.  I have tried smoothing it several ways, but cannot seem to do it.  Oh well.
This is much betterer!!  Thank you!

Comment: first - make sure that you applied scale for curve + object. second: both origin points should be the same (i would set both to 0/0/0 and move after it worked). after you did that, upload blend file again

Comment: It looks like your object is a simple elongated cube. You need to add subdivisions if you want it to bend

Comment: Hi Gorgious,Thank you for replying.  However the "cube" has about 36 loop cuts in the direction of the bend, but I will add some more at 90 degrees.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions worked.  Thank you those that answered.  The solution was to apply scale to objects (curve and seat).  I had previously applied rotation, but Not scale.

Once set up, I did have to play with the position, rotation AND scale but due to the scales lining up better, it was easier to find a solution.

[blender file](http://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SbYzkNRg%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.com/b/SbYzkNRg/))
[image: It worked]